# Matrix chain multiplication recurrence and its solution

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, dynamic-programming, recurrence-relation, matrices

We want to calculate $A_1 \times A_2 \times \cdots \times A_n$, where $A_i$ has dimensions $d_{i-1} \times d_i$.

In the classical matrix chain multiplication problem, we wish to minimize the total number of scalar multiplications. In this problem, we consider the all intermediate matrices arising in the computation (including the final result but excluding the original matrices), and the cost of a specific order is the maximal number of entries of such an intermediate matrix. As usual, we want to minimize the cost.

As an example, if $n = 2$ the answer is simply $d_0d_2$, and if $n = 3$, then there are two orders:

- $(A_1A_2)A_3$, in which the intermediate matrices are $A_1A_2,A_1A_2A_3$. The cost is therefore $\max(d_0d_2,d_0d_3)$.
- $A_1(A_2A_3)$, in which the intermediate matrices are $A_2A_3,A_1A_2A_3$. The cost is therefore $\max(d_1d_3,d_0d_3)$.

Denote by $C_{ij}$ the optimal cost of multiplying $A_i,\ldots,A_j$. We can write the following recurrence for $C_{ij}$:

$$C_{ij}=\min_{i \leq k <j} \max \{C_{i,k},C_{k+1,j},d_{i-1}d_j\},$$

with base case $C_{ii} = 0$.

> How do we get this recurrence?

Comment: I don't understand the definition of $C_{ij}$.

Comment: I still don't understand what $C_{ij}$ is. Also, I don't understand what $d_{i-1,j}$ is.

Comment: Can you explain the notation $d_{i-1,j}$? I only know what $d_i$ stands for.

Comment: If you are not sure about what you are trying to prove, the chance that you will manage to prove it is rather small.

Comment: The recurrence in your notes is different. I still have no clue what $C_{ij}$ is, and what $d_{i-1,j}$ is.

Comment: If you can give a formula for $d_{i-1,j}$, then perhaps the meaning of $C_{ij}$ can be reverse-engineered. But this is much harder if you're not sure what $d_{i-1,j}$ stands for. Instead of guessing, I suggest you ask the professor or teaching assistant what $d_{i-1,j}$ is.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to incorporate all relevant information.  Don't just leave clarifications in the comments: use the comments to help you revise the question so it will be clear to future readers.  Thank you!

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/133097/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3937537/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 2):

We get the recurrence by considering all possible ways of breaking up $A_i \times \cdots \times A_j$.

Specifically, we consider $(A_i \times \cdots \times A_k) \times (A_{k+1} \times \cdots \times A_j)$ for all relevant values of $k$, which are $i,\ldots,j-1$.

Comment: I think it's best if you worked this out on your own.